# Списки в python

Tags: python

У меня есть 2 списка, мне необходимо поочерёдно выводить элементы списка.

Пример:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3']
list2 = ['first is ','second is ', 'third is ']
```

Вывод: `first is 1 second is 2 third is 3`

Comment: Вы пытались решить эту задачу? Что конкретно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Мне именно необходим вывод сначала из одного списка, а потом из другого до конца списков

Comment: А списки у вас одинаковой длины?

Comment: Копайте в cторону `zip()`

Comment: Да, списки равны

Comment: Цикл `for i in range(len(list1))` и два `print()` внутри цикла. Чтобы вывод при каждом принте не переносился на новую строку, укажите параметр `end="` `(print(list1[i], list2[i], end=""))` вот так.

Answer (score 2):

Вот zip вариант и если он тебе не нравиться

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3']
list2 = ['first is ','second is ', 'third is ']

for v in zip(list2, list1):
    print(v[0] + v[1])
    # first is 1
    # second is 2
    # third is 3

def printTwoList(l1, l2):
    length = len(l1)
    res = l1+l2
    for i in range(0, length):
        print(res[i]+res[i+length])

printTwoList(list2, list1)

# first is 1
# second is 2
# third is 3
```

И вот для понимания как работает zip

```
class Zip(object) : 
    def __init__(self, *kwargs) -> list : 
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.length = ( len(kwargs), min( map(len, kwargs) ) )
        self.first = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self) : 
        if self.first < self.length[1] : 
            res = [self.kwargs[0][self.first]]
            for x in range(1, self.length[0] ) :
                res.append( self.kwargs[x][self.first] )
            self.first += 1
            return res
        else :
            raise StopIteration()

a = [1,2,9]
b = [3,4,8,2]
c = [5,6,5]

t = Zip( a,b,c )

print( list(zip(a,b,c)) ) # [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6), (9, 8, 5)]

print(next(t), next(t), next(t))  # [1, 3, 5] [2, 4, 6] [9, 8, 5]
```

Comment: Да всё получилось через `zip()`.

Comment: Можно короче: `' '.join(i.strip() for t in zip(list2, list1) for i in t)`

Comment: если не сразу используют zip, то разобраться в однострочном варианте сложнее, усложнить то всегда можно. Лично мое мнение, хотя это python и синтаксический сахар, будет только лучше

Answer (score 0):

Если списки одинаковые и не меняются, то можно решить задачу в лоб:

```
for i in range (0, len(list_1)):
    print(list_2[i], list_1[i], end=' ')
```

Ну, а если более экставагантное решение требуется, надо думать

Comment: Исправите, пожалуйста, отступ второй строки.